# MessageBox with Timer buttons that looks like messagebox.showwarn()

Tags: python, tkinter

I used the top answer at [MessageBox pause - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841410/messagebox-pause-python) to make a dialog box that has a timed 'OK' button on it. However, the box is pretty sad looking and I'd like it to look like a standard messagebox.showwarn() message box even taking advantage of the 'detail' parameter.

My problem is that messageboxes don't look like they are meant to be refactored and customized or sub-classed. I also tried using ttkbootstrap to put the Icon.warn inside a label, but all it did was turn all my buttons a blue color and never displayed the icon. Plus, I'd prefer not to use another library just to display a warning icon as my script is already pretty bloated.

Is there a practical way to either:

1. Subclass the messagebox.Message object to have an OK button that has a pause time before it can be pressed and also make it look like a warning messagebox; or
2. Keep my current solution using Saad's answer of subclassing a simpledialog but make it look more like a warning messagebox including the warning icon and detail lines.

Comment: You're most likely going to have to create your own dialog by inheriting from `tk.Toplevel` - that's what I do for anything that ends up more complicated than what `tkinter.messagebox` offers out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [Saad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845473/5317403) to have an icon like `MessageBox`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog

class MyDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self, title, message, icon, pause=None, master=None):
        """
        icon can be "information", "warning", "error" or "question"
        """
        self.message = message
        self.icon = icon
        self.pause = pause
        super().__init__(master, title)

    def body(self, parent):
        # get the system icon image
        self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(master=parent)
        self.tk.call(self.photo, "copy", f"::tk::icons::{self.icon}")
        # create label with the icon image and message
        ttk.Label(parent, image=self.photo, text=self.message, compound="left").pack(padx=50, pady=20)

    def buttonbox(self):
        box = ttk.Frame(self)
        state = tk.DISABLED if self.pause else tk.NORMAL
        self.ok_btn = ttk.Button(box, text="OK", width=20, command=self.ok, default=tk.ACTIVE, state=state)
        self.ok_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.cancel_btn = ttk.Button(box, text="Cancel", width=20, command=self.cancel, state=state)
        self.cancel_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        box.pack()
        if self.pause:
            self._timer()
        else:
            self._bindings()

    def _bindings(self):
        self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel)

    def _timer(self):
        if self.pause > 0:
            self.ok_btn.config(text=self.pause)
            self.pause -= 1
            self.after(1000, self._timer)
        else:
            self.ok_btn.config(text="OK", state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.cancel_btn.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self._bindings()

    def apply(self):
        self.result = True

    def cancel(self, event=None):
        if self.pause in (None, 0):
            super().cancel(event)

dlg = MyDialog("Error", "Something wrong!", icon="warning", pause=5)
print(dlg.result)
```

Result:

[image]
[image]